# Remove white space at the end of the output in C

Tags: c, whitespace

The following code is for printing the elements of a matrix in spiral order. The program works fine. The problem, however, is that the online compiler against which I'm checking the program, doesn't accept trailing white spaces at the end of the output. Could anyone give me some ideas as to how I can get around the last white space being added at the output?

For reference, my code is as follows (yes the variable names are terrible. I'm working on changing my habit of putting random variable names!!)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a[6][6];
    int i, k = 0, l = 0, m=3, n=3, j;
    scanf("%d %d",&m, &n);
    for(i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
            scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
    }
    while (k < m && l < n)
    {
        for (i = l; i < n; ++i)
            printf("%d ", a[k][i]);
        k++;
        for (i = k; i < m; ++i)
            printf("%d ", a[i][n-1]);
        n--;
        if ( k < m)
        {
            for (i = n-1; i >= l; --i)
                printf("%d ", a[m-1][i]);
            m--;
        }
        if (l < n)
        {
            for (i = m-1; i >= k; --i)
                printf("%d ", a[i][l]);
            l++;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
1 2 3

4 5 6

7 8 9
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 6 9 8 7 4 5{one extra space}
```

Any way to fix this problem?
(Also sorry for the terrible formatting. First question on StackOverflow!)

Comment: you are adding the whitespace in the above program in the `printf` statements.

Comment: use printf(" %d",a[i][j]). Simply put space before rather than after. You can use \b for backspace as well.

Comment: @dreamer yes. and without the spaces in the printf statements it'd print the output as 123698745. I do want to keep the spaces in between. Its that one space that is being added at the end which bothers the compiler.

Comment: @SiMemon I could. But then there would be one extra space at the very beginning like so " 123698745" which makes the compiler go haywire again.

Comment: Nothing to sorry about, very good formatting, especially for first question :)

Comment: @KirilKirov hah! actually the preview pane, while asking the question, wasn't showing the colours and stuff so I thought maybe I was doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code, this `for` (the first one in the `while` loop):

```
for (i = l; i < n; ++i)
    printf("%d ", a[k][i]);
```

will always be executed at least ones (because `l<n`, coming from the `while`'s condition).

Then you can just do the following:

- always add the space in front of the number
- add a single `if` check just for this very first `for`-loop (use some `bool` flag).

For example, something like:

```
bool first = true;
while (k < m && l < n)
{
    for (i = l; i < n; ++i)
    {
        if( ! first )
        {
            printf(" %d", a[k][i]);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%d", a[k][i]);
            first = false;
        }
    }
    // ....
}
```

This will be rather efficient and short solution - the `if` is in just one loop and the flag will be `true` just once (will avoid cache misses).

Comment: yes! that's really elegant! thanks! i was thinking about creating a new array to put the results in and then print out the array in the end or perhaps add a check before each printf statement. But this is much much better. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can put an `if` condition in your `for` loops

```
for (i = l; i < n; ++i)
{
        printf("%d", a[k][i]);
        if(i < n-1)
            printf(" ");
}
```

Comment: I don't think that will work for 5X5 or larger input.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck; Why not?

Comment: It will suppress the space more than once, because the while loop will now loop 2 cycles.

Answer (score 2):

You need to suppress the space when you don't need one. 
You can do it like this:

Add these declarations:

```
char *format = "%d";
int first_number = 1;
```

Add this after the first printf:

```
if (first_number) {
    /* Now we want a space between numbers */
    first_number = 0;
    format = " %d";
}
```

Change your printf:s to use the new variable:

```
            printf(format, ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

the printf() statement,

```
 printf("%d ", a[k][i]);
```

results in extra space. use

"%d"
without space or use space in the begining as,

```
" %d"
```

then at the end there wont be a extra space.
its about how you use space in your printf(). use space in a way that extra space is not present at the end as you wanted.
You can use code like this,

```
while (k < m && l < n)
    {
        for (i = l; i < n; ++i)
        {
            if(l==0&&i==0)
            {
              printf("%d", a[k][i]);
            }
            else
              printf(" %d", a[k][i]);
        }
        k++;
        for (i = k; i < m; ++i)
            printf(" %d", a[i][n-1]);
        n--;
        if ( k < m)
        {
            for (i = n-1; i >= l; --i)
                printf(" %d", a[m-1][i]);
            m--;
        }
        if (l < n)
        {
            for (i = m-1; i >= k; --i)
                printf(" %d", a[i][l]);
            l++;
        }
```

Comment: Then there will be an extra space in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a boolean variable `isFirst` to `true` before your printing out any stuff, and test it before each `printf` statement. If `isFirst`, do not print a space but set `isFirst` to `false`; else print a single space. After that, continue with printing your number without a space.

Alternative: Instead of printing your results immediately, create a `results` array. Store your results in there, and when done, print out the results in a tight loop. You can print the first number *without* a leading space, then loop over the remainder and print them *with* a leading space.

Comment: yes. i've thought about going with the alternative solution already. I'm going to try doing it with the condition check first though. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

An answer after accepted answer:

Rather than:

```
while (k < m && l < n) {
  ...
  printf("%d ", a[k][i]);
  ...
  printf("%d ", a[i][n-1]);
  ...
  printf("%d ", a[m-1][i]);
  ...
  printf("%d ", a[i][l]);
  ...
}
```

Change the format.

```
const char *format = "%d";
while (k < m && l < n) {
  ...
  printf(format, a[k][i]);
  format = " %d";
  ...
  printf(format, a[i][n-1]);
  ...
  printf(format, a[m-1][i]);
  ...
  printf(format, a[i][l]);
  ...
}
fputc('\n', stdout); // if desired.
```